# Django Admin authentication credentials not provided - HTTP 401

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

My Django app is not recognizing the credentials in the admin panel for some models. I can login, view part of the models, but for some others I see the following error message:

```
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

Interesting: there are models I can see but when I click on "Add" to add an entry, I see the error message.

Among others, I am using the following libraries:

```
Django==2.0.9
django-cors-headers==2.4.0
django-extensions==2.1.3
django-storages==1.7.1
djangorestframework==3.8.2
djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
```

In my settings.py I have the following:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'corsheaders',
    'django_extensions',
    'storages',

    'rest_framework',

    'authentication.apps.AuthenticationConfig',
    'directory.apps.DirectoryConfig',
    'metacontent.apps.MetacontentConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
]
```

and also:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        #'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated', #removed for open docs access
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 100,
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'anon': '1000/hour',
        'user': '6000/hour',
    },
}
```

When the request is NOT working, the headers of the response are the following:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Fri, 02 Nov 2018 21:50:27 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.34 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.5
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Vary: Origin
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
WWW-Authenticate: JWT realm="api"
Content-Length: 58
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

And when it is working:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 02 Nov 2018 21:50:28 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.34 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.5
Expires: Fri, 02 Nov 2018 21:50:29 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Vary: Cookie,Origin
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=8Aw8toVirE5qLSt79Nhh5tDem59qLChCrZ3i7zKkLo2NzS1UZ37SVDpjl; expires=Fri, 01-Nov-2019 21:50:29 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/
Content-Length: 3876
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

I thought about "WSGIPassAuthorization On" but if that were the issue, it would never work. Also, I have the issue both on localhost (mac) and on server (Apache with WSGIPassAuthorization On).
What am I missing? Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Will you try to comment the `authentication.app.AuthenticationConfig` in your `installed_apps` and see what it does.

Comment: Can't do that as this is where I manage the User model :-/ I used the same app name in other projects and it worked perfectly for Python 2.7 and Django 1.11, but now using Python 3.4 and Django 2.0.9

Answer (score 0):

Solution was actually quite simple.
I had a URL registered as such:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'mymodel', views.MymodelViewSet, base_name='mymodel')
```

But because there was no ^ at the start, the regex of the admin page tried to call the registered URL rather than the admin generated one. So solution was simply to add a ^:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'^mymodel', views.MymodelViewSet, base_name='mymodel')
```